# Count letters before a digit / python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function which returns the number of uppercase letters that appear in a string before a digit in the string. The variable n (what im having trouble with) is the starting point. For example if the string is "ABCDD1A" and n = 3, the function should only return the amount of uppercase letters including and after the third position, so the result should be 2. If n is greater than the length of the string, it should return 0. This is what I have at the moment, I just cant get the function to consider the starting point(n).

```
def UpperCase(st,n):
sum = 0
for i in st:
    if n > len(st):
        return sum
    if n < len(st):
        if i.isalpha():
            if i.isupper():
                sum += 1
            if i.isdigit:
                sum = sum
return sum
```

Comment: Instead of looping over the string itself, you should loop using `range`. This allows you to define your starting point. `for i in range(n, len(st))`. Since now your loop index is an integer and not a string, you may wish to make a simple temp variable to make your life easier: `c = st[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = "ABCDD1A"
n = 3
result = sum(map(len, re.findall('[A-Z]+(?=\d)', s[n:])))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Is there a way to find it without importing re? in a similar way to what i tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should add break in loop since you only want to count uppers before a number. example below

```
def UpperCase(st, n):
    total = 0
    # from starting idx n, until length of string
    for idx in range(n, len(st)):
        if st[idx].isdigit():
            # only count from starting position until first digit
            break
        elif st[idx].isupper():
            total += 1
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

## Function that returns the occurrence of capital letters after a certain index and until a digit

```
def cap(stringa, start, x=0):
    for i in stringa[start:]:
        if i.isdigit():
            break
        elif i.isalpha() and i == i.upper():
            x += 1
    return x


print(cap("ABCDD1D", 3))
```

**output:**

> **2**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a `one-liner` with `sum()` and a `generator` expression after first calculating where the first `digit` is after `n`:

```
def upperCase(st, n):
    return sum(1 for c in st[n:next(st.index(c) for c in st[n:] if c.isdigit())] if c.isupper())
```

and some tests show that it works correctly:

```
>>> upperCase("ABCDD1A", 3)
2
>>> upperCase("ABCD6GG", 3)
1
>>> upperCase("ABCD6GG", 0)
4
```